# Jenkins java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to create a global variable in Jenkins URL (https://jenkins.abc.com/cid/) by executing a groovy command. Below is my command.

java -jar C:\Temp\jenkins-cli.jar -s "https://jenkins.abc.com/cid/" -auth abc:def -remoting groovy C:\Temp\ATS \scripts\createGlobalVariable.groovy “IP_VAR_Name” “10.19.143.32” --username abc --password def

I am seeing following error

```
May 14, 2019 12:53:38 PM hudson.cli.CLI connectViaCliPort
WARNING: -auth ignored when using JNLP agent port
May 14, 2019 12:53:46 PM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
INFO: I/O error in channel Chunked connection to https://jenkins.abc.com/cid/
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
              at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:77)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
              at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
              at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
              at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
              at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
              at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:49)
              at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:140)
              at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:126)
              at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:36)
              at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)

hudson.remoting.RemotingSystemException: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@127982:Chunked connection to https://jenkins.abc.com/cid/": channel is already closed
              at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:299)
              at hudson.remoting.$Proxy1.waitForProperty(Unknown Source)
              at hudson.remoting.Channel.waitForRemoteProperty(Channel.java:1582)
              at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:151)
              at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:82)
              at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:631)
              at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:427)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@127982:Chunked connection to https://jenkins.abc.com/cid/": channel is already closed
              at hudson.remoting.Request.checkIfCanBeExecutedOnChannel(Request.java:129)
              at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.checkIfCanBeExecutedOnChannel(UserRequest.java:114)
              at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:148)
              at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:956)
              at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:283)
              ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
              at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:77)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
              at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
              at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
              at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
              at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
              at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:49)
              at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:140)
              at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:126)
              at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:36)
              at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
```

And Groovy Script is :

```
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

//Creates a global variable based on the values passed

instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()
envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)

newEnvVarsNodeProperty = null
envVars = null

if ( envVarsNodePropertyList == null || envVarsNodePropertyList.size() == 0 ) {
  newEnvVarsNodeProperty = new EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty();
  globalNodeProperties.add(newEnvVarsNodeProperty)
  envVars = newEnvVarsNodeProperty.getEnvVars()
} else {
  envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()
}
envVars.put(args[0], args[1])
instance.save()
```

Not sure why am I getting this error.

Any thoughts!